# What approach use in this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you suggest which method should be used to solve the following DE:
$$xdy-2ydx+xy^2(2xdy+ydx) = 0$$
I guess I can rewrite it in the form of Exact Equations, but it is really confusing to find $F(x,y)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-write it as
$$\frac{(xdy-2ydx)}{xy}+(2xydy+y^2dx)=0 \implies \frac{dy}{y}-2\frac{dx}{x}+d(xy^2)=0$$ Integrating we get
$$\int \left (\frac{dy}{y}-2\frac{dx}{x}+d(xy^2) \right)=0$$
$$\implies \ln y-\ln x^2+xy^2=C$$